# Is there a way to set whether text is anti-aliased in the codenameone simulator?

Tags: codenameone, draw, simulator, antialiasing

My app uses a subclass of `Label`.  I am hoping to capture a screencast (video) of the app in the simulator, to use as part of the app's "in-app tutorial".  This would either be an MP4 or an animated GIF.

At this stage, I'd like to capture the animation with text that is not anti-aliased. (I'm hoping I can get the file size down by reducing the number of colors in the GIF.  This may be a fool's errand, but I want to do the experiment...)

I've tried the following but the results (in the CN1 simulator) were still anti-aliased.

```
// This is a subclass of Label
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setAntiAliased(false);
    g.setAntiAliasedText(false);
    super.paint(g);
}
```

I also tried variants where I didn't rely on `super.paint(g)`, and instead simply drew a hard-coded "TEST" string.  It was still anti-aliased.

Comment: There is currently no exposed API to do this but I don't understand the use case for that? Why would you want that?

Comment: The anti-aliasing would introduce additional colors to the screen recording (to include as part of an embedded tutorial, in app).  In the case of an animated GIF, there is a tool https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/ that will attempt to reduce the number of colors in order to lower the file size.  I was able to  reduce the number of colors to 16 (in a test recording of my app) without harming the quality too much.  When I reduced to 8 colors there were artifacts around the letters, although the app was still recognizable, and the file size dropped significantly.

Comment: At this stage I am leaning toward embedding either a series of MP4, or animated GIF, to use as part of the in app tutorial.  I won't disable anti-aliasing in the actual app, just in order to capture these recordings, to help show how the app works.

Comment: That's an interesting use case. Personally I use youtube videos so I didn't pay attention to the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that and I'm not sure why you would want it. But if you want to just demonstrate/test something in the simulator it's pretty easy to edit the Codename One source code and toggle anti aliasing off either in Graphics itself or in the `DefaultLookAndFeel` class.

To use the source code see this http://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try!